# How can I use do.call calculate the mean of a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, do.call

I know, I can use `sapply` and `colMeans` to `rowMeans` for the mean value of a data.frame. But now, I am learning `do.call` and want to try it with `do.call()`.

I tried different way to do that, but I can't get the result what I want.

For example, I want get the result as the same from `sapply`:

```
myIris <- iris[1:4]
head(myIris)
sapply(myIris, mean)

#Here is the result what I want
#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#5.843333     3.057333     3.758000     1.199333
```

So I tried this with do.call() with different way, all told me wrong!

```
do.call("mean", myIris) # Wrong!
do.call("mean", x=myIris) # Wrong!
do.call("mean", list(x=myIris)) # Wrong!
....
```

Do you know how to do it with the do.call?

Comment: If you are looking for column wise mean, the do.call approach will not work.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but `do.call` expects a `list` not a `data.frame`.

Comment: @akrun , Thanks for the answer, but do you know, how can I use it for the row means? I can change my questions, because I want to know both with  row means and col means.

Comment: You could try `do.call("colMeans", list(myIris))`

Comment: @Pascal actually I already tried with different list, like as.list(), list(), c(), vector(), as.vector(), everything possible, but none of them works...

Comment: Why you cant run `rowMeans` and `colMeans` separately?.  BTW, using `colMeans(myIris)` is more compact than doing it within `do.call`

Comment: `c()`, `vector()` and `as.vector()` don't create `list` object. However, I don't see the need of `do.call` here. Directly using `colMeans` is faster and provides the same result.

Comment: @akrun I am just tried to understand a little better about do.call(), I recently know that, many functions like apply uses the for loop, it will be slow. So if I use the do.call, which may be more efficient. And if I use colMeans(myIris), and rowMeans(myIris), I don't need to use do.call().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need both `rowMeans` and `colMeans` to be run using `lapply/sapply`

```
lapply(c('colMeans', 'rowMeans'), function(x) get(x)(myIris))
#[[1]]
#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#    5.843333     3.057333     3.758000     1.199333 

#[[2]]
#  [1] 2.550 2.375 2.350 2.350 2.550 2.850 2.425 2.525 2.225 2.400 2.700 2.500
# [13] 2.325 2.125 2.800 3.000 2.750 2.575 2.875 2.675 2.675 2.675 2.350 2.650
# [25] 2.575 2.450 2.600 2.600 2.550 2.425 2.425 2.675 2.725 2.825 2.425 2.400
# [37] 2.625 2.500 2.225 2.550 2.525 2.100 2.275 2.675 2.800 2.375 2.675 2.350
# [49] 2.675 2.475 4.075 3.900 4.100 3.275 3.850 3.575 3.975 2.900 3.850 3.300
# [61] 2.875 3.650 3.300 3.775 3.350 3.900 3.650 3.400 3.600 3.275 3.925 3.550
# [73] 3.800 3.700 3.725 3.850 3.950 4.100 3.725 3.200 3.200 3.150 3.400 3.850
# [85] 3.600 3.875 4.000 3.575 3.500 3.325 3.425 3.775 3.400 2.900 3.450 3.525
# [97] 3.525 3.675 2.925 3.475 4.525 3.875 4.525 4.150 4.375 4.825 3.400 4.575
#[109] 4.200 4.850 4.200 4.075 4.350 3.800 4.025 4.300 4.200 5.100 4.875 3.675
#[121] 4.525 3.825 4.800 3.925 4.450 4.550 3.900 3.950 4.225 4.400 4.550 5.025
#[133] 4.250 3.925 3.925 4.775 4.425 4.200 3.900 4.375 4.450 4.350 3.875 4.550
#[145] 4.550 4.300 3.925 4.175 4.325 3.950
```

---

Or use

```
 lapply(list(colMeans, rowMeans), do.call, list(myIris))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `colMeans` instead of `mean` would give you the desired result

```
do.call("colMeans", list(myIris))

# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#    5.843333     3.057333     3.758000     1.199333
```